# scp from Linux to Windows: 'C:\Program' is not recognized error

Tags: linux, windows, bash, ssh, scp

In my linux machine, I'm trying to send a file over to a Windows machine via:

```
scp fileNameA user@windowServer:fileNameA
```

I get the following message:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

What's prompting this message?

I've installed OpenSSH on the windows machine, and I can successfully SSH into it. I don't want to use WinSCP, FileZilla, etc, because I have to automate this in a script. This has to be done from the Linux machine, so I'm not interested in doing pscp from the Windows machine.

Comment: I suspect you will need `C:\\Program\\..` to escape the path components so that `\P` isn't taken as a literal `'P'`, etc.. If that doesn't do it, let me know and I'll boot a Win10 machine and send it something from a Linux box.

Comment: I tried the following from a linux, and it didn't work. :( At the moment, I don't care about the specific Windows directory.

Comment: Probably the space in `Program Files` is causing the problem.  Place the all filenames inside quotes.

Comment: That's what I assumed, but I haven't specified "Program Files" as the directory anywhere. I tried to scp into a specified directory (inside quotes), and that didn't work. Also, I checked the PATH variable, and didn't see anything unusual.

Comment: Maybe you want to provide us a piece of code to debug?

Comment: I don't think there's a code, per se, to debug. I tried to send a simple txt file that contains "Hello World" via the command in question in linux terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem today.

I think it is an issue in the new version of OpenSSH, which was published few days ago. I reverted previous version (v7.6.1.0p1-Beta), which was working correctly on my VM from https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases and problem was fixed without any changes in configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the same problem by moving my installation of OpenSSH from `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH` to `C:\OpenSSH`.

I had to first uninstall it properly using the provided script in Win32-OpenSSH and then follow back the information provided there https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH but only changing the path to C:\OpenSSH.

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar issue today, trying to copy files to a Windows server running [OpenSSH-Win64](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/tag/v8.1.0.0p1-Beta). I solved the problem by adding `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH`, which is the recommended installation location, to the Windows path:

1. Open the *Control Panel*, go to the *System and Security* section and open up *System*.
2. Click on *Advanced System Settings* and, in the System Properties dialog box, click *Environmental Variables*.
3. In the *System Variables* section of the dialog box, select *Path* and click *Edit...*.
4. Click *New*, add the OpenSSH folder path and click *OK* to apply the change.

Then, do not forget to restart the OpenSSH service, either in the service management console or by running `net stop sshd`, followed by `net start sshd` in an elevated console.